# How can I get specified querystring key-value on custom log files with powershell?

Tags: powershell, query-string, logfile

I've tried to parse own custom log files rows and I except to get some spesific rows which header value is involved querystring values and included spesific key-value

**I spesified some example log file rows as below :**

```
2016-01-04 14:07:06 192.168.1.0 - example.com GET MainPage a=2&b=20&c=12-10&d=apple 
2016-01-04 14:07:07 192.168.1.0 - example.com GET Search x=2&y=20&c=56-32-12&d=orange 
2016-01-04 14:07:08 192.168.1.0 - example.com GET ProdView r=1&b=20&c=24&d=orange
2016-01-04 14:09:38 192.168.1.0 - example.com GET ProdView a=2&b=20&c=1-23e&d=orange
```

**What I want for my own powershell result**

```
2016-01-04 14:07:08 192.168.1.0 - example.com GET ProdView r=1&b=20&c=24&d=orange
```

Output must show which querystring parameters contains c and it points just numeric value(it mustn't contains any '-' character)

My own query as below :

```
Import-Csv -Encoding UTF8 .\logs\x.log -header A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H -delimiter ' ' | where {$_.H -match "c"} | select-string H
```

But I've blocked when I attempt to parse querystring parameters

Best regards

Comment: I count at least **9** columns in your file, but only **8** header names

Comment: can you provide an example of your expected result when this is working properly?

Comment: You're right , I edited my post ,thanks

Comment: Hi @AnthonyStringer I edited my post , isn't it clear ? My expected rows must contains c parameter and that parameter must be included only numeric value.

Comment: The log sample use 2 and 3 spaces to delimit fields now, is that how the actual file looks? Also, you may want to use `Select-Object` and not `Select-String` if you're interested in just the query-string

Comment: guess it might be an overkill but how about ConvertFrom-String? ...if the logs are that custom

Comment: Hi @MathiasR.Jessen , I edited my post , I wrongly set more than one space , thanks for reply.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regular expression to match the log entries where the query-string contains the information you describe - parameter `c` is present, has only numerical digits as its value:

```
$_.H -match '(^|&)c=\d+(&|$)' 

# (^|&)      either start-of-string or the character &
# c=         the literal string "c="
# \d+        one or more digits
# ($|&)      either end-of-string or the character &
```

Answer (score 1):

in your example, you have double and triple spaces, but this example only works if there is just a single space.

```
Import-Csv -Encoding UTF8 .\logs\x.log -header A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H -delimiter ' ' | ? h -match 'c[^-]+(&|$)' | select -exp h
```

or maybe something like this:

```
gc .\logs\x.log | % {$($_ -replace ' +', ' ').trim().split(' ')[-1]} | ? {$_ -match 'c[^-]+(&|$)'}
```

Comment: ı used your code , and it works , thanks for your helping.